# execute shell with timeout c#

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Hi all i have created a small application to execute "Command Prompt" with a command so far  i created a simple method with thread sleep

```
public static string Executecmd(string command, int sleepSec) {
    try {
        string result = null;
        System.Threading.Thread objThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {
            result = ExecuteCommandSync(command);
        });
        objThread.IsBackground = true;
        objThread.Start();
        while (objThread.IsAlive == true) {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepSec * 1000);
            objThread.Abort();
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception x) {
        Console.WriteLine(x.Message + "\n" + x);
        return null;
    }
}
```

it works fine but even if the command executed finish it stays sleep until the thread sleep is completed so my question is how can i create a method which will excecute it and sleep for 5 secs and if it completed it stops else wait 5 sec then abort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23f7b1ct.aspx) with a timespan.

```
    System.Threading.Thread objThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate() {
        result = ExecuteCommandSync(command);
    });
    objThread.IsBackground = true;
    objThread.Start();

    //Waits here for "sleepSec" seconds or until the thread finishes, whichever is shorter.
    if(objThread.Join(new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sleepSec)) == false)
    {
        //Only executes this code of the thread did not finish before the timeout.
        objThread.Abort();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) for this purpose.